# Normalizing Data on scale of 0 to1 in Excel

Tags: excel, normalization

I need data in excel to return with a normalized value between 0 and 1. Following another forum, I tried the formula `=A1-MIN($A$1:$A$8)/(MAX($A$1:$A$8)-MIN($A$1:$A$8))` which returns with the same value as A1. Not sure where I went wrong. Data is as follows, but should a value between 0 and 1

- 24778.0
- 25439.0
- 26372.0
- 16833.0
- 20909.0
- 202182.0
- 15041.0
- 5573.0

Comment: `=A1/Max(A1:A8)`. Also, check the description of the excel tag. Questions like this are better fit for http://superuser.com

Comment: Yes, your goal is to divide each number by the maximum.

Comment: @Slai That won't normalise the range to [0, 1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a pair of parentheses.

```
=(A1-MIN($A$1:$A$8))/(MAX($A$1:$A$8)-MIN($A$1:$A$8))
```